# AWS PowerShell to retrieve the Bucket name and S3 key of source bundle of Elastic Beanstalk Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-powershell, aws-ebs

How do I get the S3 key and bucket name of source bundle of application that is running on an elastic beanstalk environment?
Suppose I deploy a java application on an elastic beanstalk Environment and I have its environment name and version label by using this information how do I get the S3 key and bucket name related to that application source bundle and i want to retrieve this information using AWS PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SourceBundle` property on the response of the `Get-EBApplicationVersion` cmdlet contains the S3 Location of the application verson's source bundle.

### Examples

List available results: (see linked documentation for pagination options)

```
(Get-EBApplicationVersion).SourceBundle

S3Bucket         S3Key
--------         -----
myBucket1        myKey1
myBucket1        myKey2
...              ...
```

Filter on application name and version label:

```
(Get-EBApplicationVersion -ApplicationName myApp -VersionLabel myVersion).SourceBundle

S3Bucket         S3Key
--------         -----
myBucket         myKey
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - Get-EBApplicationVersion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EBApplicationVersion.html)
- [AWS Documentation - Amazon.ElasticBeanstalk.Model.ApplicationVersionDescription](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=EB/TEBApplicationVersionDescription.html&tocid=Amazon_ElasticBeanstalk_Model_ApplicationVersionDescription)